# How to detect if an Android app runs in screen compatibility mode?

Tags: java, android

I'm building an Android library to be used in other projects (Android 2.1 and above) that might or might not run in screen compatibility mode (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html).

Is there a way to detect if an application (in my case, the application that included my library) runs in screen compatibility mode?

Assuming that I don't want to run on devices with width <= 320dp, does checking if the application has width <= 320dp can be considered as a good indication that it runs in compatibility mode?
I'm don't really like it as the documentation says:

> **Note**: Currently, screen compatibility mode only emulates handset
>   screens with a 320dp width, so screen compatibility mode is not
>   applied to any device if your value for android:compatibleWidthLimitDp
>   is larger than 320.

Comment: You can check how to enable the Screen Compatibility Mode here :http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html#Enable and derive your check, based on that.

Answer (score 0):

A viable solution on API 17:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

Point realSizePoint = new Point();
manager.getRealSize(realSizePoint);

Point scaledSizePoint = new Point();
manager.getSize(scaledSizePoint);
```

and then compare `realSizePoint` and `scaledSizePoint` coordinates.
It might sound hacky and I haven't tested this code but it should do the job.

Comment: In API 17 life is good :) - I need a solution for Android 2.1+ (will edit my question)